# Losing authentication after refreshing the page (AngularJS, NodeJS)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

So I have authentication for my web app. This is my authentication controller.

```
myTodoList.controller('authController', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $location) {
$scope.user = { username: '', password: '' };
$scope.error_message = '';

$scope.login = function() {
    $http.post('/auth/login', $scope.user).success(function(data) {
        if (data.state == 'success') {
            $rootScope.authenticated = true;
            $rootScope.current_user = data.user.username;
            $location.path('/app');
        } else {
            $scope.error_message = data.message;
        }
    });
};

$scope.register = function() {
    $http.post('/auth/signup', $scope.user).success(function(data) {
        if (data.state == 'success') {
            $rootScope.authenticated = true;
            $rootScope.current_user = data.user.username;
            $location.path('/app');
        } else {
            $scope.error_message = data.message;
        }
    });
};
```

});

This works fine, I get my authentication after logging in or making a new registration. But After refreshing the page I lose my authentication. I think these lines generate the problem.

```
var myTodoList = angular.module("myTodoList", ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']).run(function($http, $rootScope) {
$rootScope.authenticated = false;
$rootScope.current_user = 'Guest';

$rootScope.signout = function() {
    $http.get('auth/signout');
    $rootScope.authenticated = false;
    $rootScope.current_user = 'Guest';
};
});
```

At the top of my `maincontroller.js` I have this `$rootScope.authenticated = false;` line. This is needed I know but this could be the line that says it should be false instead of true after refreshing. What should I do to get around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing the data on the rootScope, store it in the sessionStorage instead - this will persist across refreshes

https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage